# How to connect remotely to the Ubuntu CLI from a Mac?

Tags: command-line, mac, remote, remote-access

I have a mac and I want to access my ubuntu Desktop's hardware remotely from anywhere to run some programs. I am aware of apps like teamviewer however I am only interested in using Ubuntu's terminal from my own mac terminal to run those programs without using the other GUI elements of my desktop OS. I was wondering if it is possible, if so how?

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect to your machine through SSH. Here is a [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-to-connect-to-a-remote-server-in-ubuntu) on how to do it. In summary:

1. Open MAC terminal and type:

`ssh {your ubuntu user}@{your ubuntu IP}`

2. It will prompt for a password, type your Ubuntu's user password.
3. If all went ok, the prompt you have is now your ubuntu prompt.

Remember you need to [have an ssh server listening](https://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-enable-ssh-ubuntu/) on your Ubuntu machine.

Take in account that if what you want to do is run X applications in your MAC (i.e. run an application that has windows) you will need to connect your X server from your Ubuntu machine to your Mac. Here is another [tutorial](https://uisapp2.iu.edu/confluence-prd/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=280461906) for that.